# Why it is "String" instead of "java.lang.String" - Scala?

Tags: string, scala, types, type-inference

I am kind of confused by the difference between `String` in Scala and the `java.lang.String`.

When I do the following, it shows the `String`.

```
scala> val msg = "Hello, World!"
msg: String = Hello, World!
```

However, as how it is done in the link: [First Steps in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/first-steps-in-scala.html#footnote2-2)

It is shown as `java.lang.String`:

```
scala> val msg = "Hello, world!"
msg: java.lang.String = Hello, world!
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: That link just used an older scala version. It's the same thing, `String` is an alis for `java.lang.String`. Don't worry about it, it's unimportant.

Comment: So in Scala running on JVM, there is no difference between `String` and `java.lang.String`?

Comment: But is there some additional implementation on Scala's String over Java's? Such as some new methods?

Comment: @ChangLiu no, but it seems like it. That's a (good) separate question though.

Comment: @ChangLiu If you want to stop worrying, just open Predef.scala. You'll find the following line there: type String        = java.lang.String. So yeah! There is no difference at all

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4e564efb04e508ccc0f479cf1a25331501927d88/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L134